# How to use content_for & yield_content in middleman using slim

Tags: padrino, slim, middleman

I've tried prepending content_for with =, == or - without luck :)

index.slim

```
- content_for(:senarios) do
  h1 Some content
```

layout.slim

```
== yield_content(:senarios)
```

Hope somebody got a solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this should have a padrino tag if it is for slim, which is a php framework?

Answer (score 1):

The example should work fine.

You capture content with `content_for` and insert it in the layout file with `yield_content`. You can omit the parentheses if you want.

If you use standard Slim settings you need two equal signs. Otherwise the output will be escaped and you will see `<h1>Some content</h1>` instead of `Some content` in the rendered output.

I also use this with Middleman and Slim. No issues. Can you please provide more code, errors, etc.?

The only thing which is looking suspicious is the filename **index.slim**. It should be **index.html.slim**.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem, and solved it.

You should change

```
- content_for(:eyecatch) do
```

to

```
= content_for(:eyecatch) do
```

nested html attributes should no longer be duplicated.